# Req.Headers.host is undefined in nodejs application

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i am newbie to node js technology. when i hosted my application in local server it is working fine.But When I hosted my application(https://www.example.com) in https server, then my application is crashing because of below error.
`req.headers.host.indexOf('someDoamin') is undefined`.
Why i am getting `req.headers.host` is null? kinldy help me. it stopped my application to go in to live.

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: Rather try to display the object req.headers and see if the host is inside the attribute host, in another one or other.

Comment: `req.headers.host.indexOf('someDoamin') is undefined` - this does not mean `req.headers.host` is null as per my understanding.

Comment: @Mohit- then what might be the reason i am getting error and eventually my server is getting crashed?

Comment: What version of Node are you using?

Comment: @Mohit-node js 4.7v